# Interpretation of a regression coefficients plot

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization

I am a noob of regression so this might be a very simple question.

I have seen many plots of the regression coefficients but I am not sure how to interpret and make these plots. For example, below is a figure from a paper, suggesting that novel submissions are more favored by Top journals.

[image]

My question is :

(1) How to make this kind of visualization? Does it just convert the novelty (a continuous measurement) into a categorical variable with five categories and run the regression, then plot the coefficients of each category and the confidence intervals?

(2) Why shouldn't I just plot the actual proportion of submissions with a certain level of novelty to get accepted by the journals? (i.e., accepted submissions / total submissions)

Comment: How can "prob" (assuming it means "probability") be negative, as shown in the graph?

Comment: @BigBendRegion The paper might give the wrong name for the Y-axis. They are essentially the coefficients of an OLS model with Novelty quintile {2,3,4,5} as dummies.

Comment: Oh ok. Seems to me that could have treated quintile as continuous, interacted it with journal type, then drawn the graph of the predicted probabilities to give something that is simpler and more easily interpreted.